# How Can I Save a Generated Symbol File?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, symbols, visual-studio-debugging

I'm testing my app with [Project White](http://white.codeplex.com/). The binaries for this project include a DLL from the Castle project: Castle.DynamicProxies2.dll (or something along those lines). Unfortunately, a symbol (PDB) file is not provided for this DLL. A bunch of the other DLL's do have their own symbol files.

When I run my UITest it takes a lot of time to generate the symbol file for this Castle DLL. I would like to save this generated DLL somewhere so it doesn't have to generate it all the time.

I have a symbol cache folder in my Visual Studio settings and when I'm running the app and I press "Load all symbols" I get a messagebox telling me it's downloading the symbol file for the Castle DLL. However, it does not appear in my cache folder (probably because it's a proprietary non-Microsoft DLL). The option "always load symbols next to modules" is turned on. If I turn it off, not even the symbols for my own project get loaded. The Castle DLL is copied to the output folder, otherwise it won't even run.

Is there any way to keep this auto-generated symbol file instead of having it created every time? I've looked into temp-folders, but couldn't find it.

Comment: PDB files are not generated from a compiled DLL since the data needed to accurately generate them is no longer present in the DLL, only in the source code (e.g. local variable names). They are usually included with the DLL for debugging purposes. An approximation of the PDB can be recreated using a decompiler, but you don't seem to be using one. So what exactly do you mean by "generate the symbol file"? Are you sure something is generated?

Comment: Well, Visual Studio tells me "Loading Symbol Files for Castle..." I hoped there was a way to save this or tell VS to NOT look for it as it takes quite a bit of time everytime. Behavior seems gone now though, don't know what I changed. I changed the debugging options to only load symbols for my own solutiom assemblies while still loading the symbol files next to modules.

Answer (score 0):

Those kinds of folders themselves have a few bugs associated with them. As found from previous experience, The first attempted solution should be restarting your computer then reopening the VS. The folder should return to its standard settings and should behave normally (for a time). Still haven't found the VS action that causes the misbehavior with the folder tho. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx is where I'm currently searching from, In case you see something there I do not.